# Save PPT File Name where Value from Excel Column

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to make a VBA macro where You can save each slide with Different Files names, the value of each File Name will come from a specific column of Excel file.
Here's the code that I've been trying so far..

```
Dim oWB As Object
Dim oXL As Object
Dim xlWS As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim FName As String
Dim xlColumn As String
Dim getName As String
Dim r As Long
Dim m As Long

' Open Excel File
Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
strFile = oXL.GetOpenFilename("Excel Worksheets (*.xlsx),*.xlsx", , "Select Excel file")
If strFile = "False" Then
    Beep
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set oWB = GetObject(Class:="Excel.Application")
If oWB Is Nothing Then
    Set oWB = CreateObject(Class:="Excel.Application")
    If oWB Is Nothing Then
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
On Error GoTo 0 ' ErrHandler
oWB.Visible = msoCTrue

xlColumn = CStr(InputBox("What Column of Worksheet?", "Column Designation"))

Set xlWS = oWB.Workbook.Open(strFile, , , msoFalse)
m = oWB.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For r = m To 2 Step -1
    FName = oWB.worksheets("Sheet1").Range(xlColumn & r).Value
Next r
```

While running the macro I'm getting an error:
**Application defined or object defined error**

```
Set xlWS = oWB.worksheets.Open(strFile, , , msoFalse)
```

Comment: Because You are getting error on `Set oWB = GetObject(Class:="Excel.Application")`, oWB is Nothing, and this is inside error handling method, that's why the error appears on `xlWS`

Comment: Your use of late binding isn't speeding up code execution. Instead it's slowing down your comprehension of the code you write. You have oXL, oWB and XlWS (at least two different syntax rules) all down as objects. oXL is an Excel.Application, oWB is an Excel.Workbook and XlWS is an Excel.Worksheet. With that said, `Set xlWS = oWB.worksheets.Open(strFile, , , msoFalse)` can't possibly work because you can't *Open* a worksheet. In order to use early binding you need to set a reference to Excel in `Tools`. Intellisense would alert you to unavailable methods.

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of information provided, this code is actually being execute in VBA of PowerPoint, and I would like to know if its possible.